# Formula for height before rotation on a grid

Tags: geometry

I am working on a design using mostly rectangles on a grid, which will sometimes get rotated in intervals of 15 degrees. After the rectangles are rotated, the height, or distance between the highest and lowest y-coordinates to be more specific, needs to be equal.

For example, I have a non-rotated rectangle that is 50px wide by 500px high. When I rotate it 45 degrees, it becomes 383.742px by 383.742px. If I try to stretch it after rotating to get the desired height, the rectangle loses it's thickness (or becomes too thick). I have gotten a few parts done through trial and error and tweaking, but figure I could be much more efficient if I could put a formula into a calculator or write a script that will get me the desired height given the rotation degrees and width of the initial rectangle.

I've tried Googling this, but it's all foreign to me. The closest explanation I saw made no sense to me, so please explain it like I'm 5.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit:
[The first rectangle is 500px by 50px, the next one is that rotated by 45 degrees. The rectangle after is 657.107px by 50px, causing it to be contained in a 500px by 500px box when rotated 45 degrees. The rectangle, if rotated backwards, still maintains the 50px width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz52a.png)

As mentioned before, I am getting the desired heights by trial and error and seeing that I will have all different widths and heights as I progress, a formula would make this process much more efficient.

Comment: What do you mean by "thickness" of the rectangle? What you mean Y distance? A drawing could help.

Comment: Thickness is the width of the actual rectangle. I'm using them as thick lines so to speak. And since I'm doing this on a grid, the highest point on the Y-axis minus the lowest point on the Y-axis would be the height of the containing box, which in this situation needs to be 500px.

Comment: Is this a square box? What is its center - if of importance?